# pure unblocked code, how to achieve?

Tags: javascript

While going throug a tutorial
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Patterns-Practices-Symposium-Online/pattern-practices-symposium-2013/Windows-8-JavaScript

I found code snippet like this
[image]

but if you see method not_blocking(), its still waiting for doExpensiveComputationOn() method to finish (although for only first time). Can I even bypass that too? So it does not wait for even single call of expensive method.

Comment: At some point the work has to be done. If you are worried about blocking the main thread, you could put the heavy load to a Worker.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript runs as a single thread of execution (except for webworkers - and even then it can vary). It looks as if it's multi-tasking as it [uses an task queue](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/); the setImmediate() function just adds the the function at the end of the task queue.

The setimmediate function is an MSIE only function and I would recomend NOT using it. You can do something similar with setTimeout(processNext, 0); although the semantics are slightly different on some browsers in relation to the window.onload event) or use the [yield() / generator construct](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) in recent versions of javascript.

[Webworkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers), or seperate frames/windows is the only way to get javascript running truly in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

All that `not_blocking` is doing is delaying the execution after every item in the array, so that UI (and other) events can be processed in between.

If you want the function to return momentarily, just change the last line from `processNext()` to `setImmediate(processNext);`. But `doExpensiveComputationOn` will still, at some point, block this thread. As Sirko commented; If you are worried about blocking the main thread, use a background worker.